# Why can I not populate a custom Button ArrayList with my custom Buttons?

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist, android-custom-view

Here is part of my custom Button class, Tile:

```
public class Tile extends Button {

// Position of this view in AL tiles.
private int index;
// Height of tile in pixels.
private int layout_height;
// Width of tile in pixels.
private int layout_width;


public Tile (Context context){
    super(context);
}


public Tile (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setUpAttributes(attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    layout_height = heightMeasureSpec;
    layout_width = widthMeasureSpec;
}

private void setUpAttributes(AttributeSet attrs){
    TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Tile, 0, 0);
    try {
        index = a.getIndex(R.styleable.Tile_index);
        columnPosition = a.getInt(R.styleable.Tile_columnPosition, 0);
        rowPosition = a.getInt(R.styleable.Tile_rowPosition, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

I can directly inflate any number of instances of this class to a GridView. The problem arises when I attempt to use this class in other classes, particularly when I try to change the values of the variables. For instance, in my custom GridView class, I want to populate an ArrayList that holds objects of type Tile. This is how I am doing this:

```
public void populateTileCollection() {
    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < getRowCount(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < getColumnCount(); x++) {
            Tile tile = (Tile)findViewById(R.id.tile);
            tile.setIndex(index);
            tile.setYCoordinate(y);
            tile.setXCoordinate(x);
            tiles.add(tile);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have these setter methods properly defined with accurate variables in my Tile class. When I run the program, I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.app.speedsweeper.speedsweeper.Tile.setIndex(int)' on a null object reference
```

If I skip the programmatic work and go directly to the inflation of these tiles, it works. In fact, while inflating them I can set their properties. However, when I try to access them after they have been inflated, the same error occurs.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Well it's obvious from the error that your `Tile tile = (Tile)findViewById(R.id.tile);` is returning null, so the likely cause is that the Tile is not actually inflated when you think it is. You may need to post the rest of your code that shows how and when you inflate your Tile, or when it is that you specifically call this code in relation to that.

Comment: In the example above, I have not inflated them yet. Do I need to inflate each Tile before changing their properties programmatically?

Comment: Yes, that is your problem. Before adjusting any View properties programmatically, the View must be inflated, otherwise it doesn't exist in memory yet because the system hasn't instantiated it. If you need more help, feel free to post your Activity/Fragment code where you are calling this stuff, and I'll provide an answer to show how to achieve this.